# Free CSS3 Editor

Tags: gratis, css, html-editor

I'm looking for a **free/gratis** (online or offline) CSS 3 Editor.

I found this one http://www.cssportal.com/online-css-editor but it is way too basic.

Plataforms: **online / windows.**

Comment: What features do you want? If that is "too basic", what is missing. Which o/s for offline use? The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to Google, I have done it for you http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/top-css-editors-reviewed/

Comment: Visual Studio isn't bad either and there is also a free version (community edition 2013)

Comment: Thanks for your update, Azevedo – but that's still not sufficient to re-open the question. See the first comment (of Mawg) for what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have given so little information that it is difficult to advise you.

However, you can hardly go wrong with [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/), since it's a project from the The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) and so shines in the area of standards compliance and accessibility.

> Work on Amaya started at W3C in 1996 to showcase Web technologies in a
>   fully-featured Web client. The main motivation for developing Amaya
>   was to provide a framework that can integrate as many W3C technologies
>   as possible. It is used to demonstrate these technologies in action
>   while taking advantage of their combination in a single, consistent
>   environment.
>
> `Amaya started as an HTML + CSS style sheets editor`.

Comment: Except that the last version was released on 18 January 2012, and a lot has changed since then.

Comment: I approved an edit that changed the link in your answer to a link to the actual software, feel free to edit/rollback.

Answer (score 1):

[Backets](http://brackets.io/) is an open source HTML, JS and CSS editor sponsored by Adobe. It's clean and comfortable to use if you already know CSS. It includes a "live preview" option and can extract design information from PSD files. There are also extensions for you to add extra features.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you:

- **Liveweave** (http://liveweave.com)
  is a HTML5, CSS3 & JavaScript editor with real-time (live) preview

Comment: Why? Have you used it? What features make it stand out? Or did you just Google & paste the first hit?

Comment: I have used it in the past and I was very comfortable with the features it offers. CSS3 which is one of your request more than this I was using other tools may be less relevant to you as color palette, text generators and so on...

Comment: It wasn't my question. Since you are new around here, I was pointing out that we like more detail in our answers. Even that comment helped a little, so I up-voted it. Welcome aboard!

Comment: What @Mawg was pointing to is [what makes a quality question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) (I recommend to check that link ;) Also, important details (as your previous comment) should be integrated with your answer itself (you can always [edit] it to improve) – in the comments it might get lost. At this place usually comes the hint to point out how your recommendation meets the OP's requirements – but considering the OP didn't specify any, that would be in vain. Still, one thing was specified: is it free? Does it work online – or offline?